# YUI asyncRequest: POST parameters are missing

Tags: struts, yui, struts-1

I am using YUI 2.6 with Struts 1.2 java web application.

I am getting an intermittent issue with POST `asyncRequest`. Some of the requests that the server receives do not have any parameters.

Most of the the times it works fine. It is very difficult to reproduce and it happens only with our customer machines. We have not been able to reproduce at our environment. I have spent quite some time to find the root cause.

Web browsers are IE 7, 8 or 9. I would appreciate any help.

I looked at [this blog](http://www.bigdumbdev.com/2010/02/yui-struts2-asyncrequest-post.html) but did not help because I was logging some parts of the requests and parameters in which content-type header was coming properly to the server.

Code:

```
new AjaxWrapper().asyncRequest( "<%=request.getContextPath()%>" + "/ajax/setValues.do",
{
    numberCheck: numberCheck,
    documentId: docBean.documentId,
    values: JSON.stringify( valueMap ),
    applyToF: applyToFCheckbox.checked,
    codeExternalF: (applyToFCheckbox.checked && codeExternalF.checked),
    applyToN: applyToNCheckbox.checked,
    codeExternalN: (applyToNCheckbox.checked && codeExternalN.checked)
},
{
    success: function( messageBeanJsonList, response, argument ) {
        // some code here
    },
    failure: function( messages ) {
        // some code here
    },
    after: function( messageBeanJsonList, response, argument ) {
        // some code here
    }, 
    argument: { codingPanel: mainCodingPanel, changedValues: changedValues }
},
AjaxWrapper.Methods.Post
);
```

Method to encode the parameters:

```
_encodeParameters: function(parameters) {       
    var params = new Array();

    if (parameters) {
        for(var name in parameters) {
            if (YAHOO.lang.isArray(parameters[name])) {
                for(var i=0; i<parameters[name].length; i++) {
                    params.push(encodeURIComponent(name) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(parameters[name][i]));
                }
            }
            else {
                params.push(encodeURIComponent(name) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(parameters[name]));
            }
        }
    }

    return params.join("&");
}
```

Comment: are you encoding your post parameters with json before sending them ? , can you post a sample of your code?

Comment: Yes. I encode the parameters before sending them to the server. I have edited the post and added some code. Basically I have a wrapper around YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest.